# how do i hide file type use apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i am coding a PHP website, and now want to hide the PHP file type in URL. for example use

```
http://.../signup
```

replace the URL

```
http://.../signup.php
```

how should i do in my apache configure file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to append `.php` if the requested path with that prefix maps onto an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

Now all you need to do is to use the paths without the trailing `.php` in your documents.

Answer (score 0):

didn't try it, but this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```